# Unable to parse the entire UDP message at client side

Tags: java, string, sockets, udp, tokenize

This is the String sent at UDP server side:
S:0 T:1 FL:4 IP:127.0.0.1 P:9000

I am able to tokenize and print up until the last word, when I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9000  
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)    
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)  
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)  
at com.acn.fog.listener.UdpListener.tokenizeIotIntoPacket(UdpListener.java:119)  
at com.acn.fog.listener.UdpListener.run(UdpListener.java:43)  
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Server code:

```
    clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(); // make a Datagram socket  
    byte[] sendData = new byte[data.getBytes().length]; // make a Byte array of the data to be sent  
    sendData = data.getBytes(); // get the bytes of the message  
    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port); // craft the message to be sent  
    clientSocket.send(sendPacket); // send the message
```

Client code:

```
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[10000]; // data size not to exceed ~10KB  
    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,   receiveData.length); // receive the response  
    serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);  
    // Tokenize received IOT packet into String  
    String iotPacketString = new String(receivePacket.getData());
```

Appreciate any help on this issue.  Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't calling `Integer.parseInt` somewhere?

Comment: It looks like you may just need to `trim` your String first before calling `parseInt` but I can not tell and you have not provided to correct code.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thanks a lot. I did not use trim. Now I used trim and my parsing works without issues. 
I was confused that I had to deal with some EOL characters, as the sender code was not appending any spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unable to parse the entire UDP message at client side

You are parsing *more* than the entire UDP message:

```
String iotPacketString = new String(receivePacket.getData());
```

Invalid. You're ignoring the length. That should be:

```
String iotPacketString = new String(receivePacket.getData(), receivePacket.getOffset(), receivePacket.getLength());
```

Comment: Thanks. To me this seems to make sense than adding trim(), which also worked.

Comment: `trim()` would not be correct. Any message could correctly contain leading or trailing spaces, and there could be other data left at the end of teh byte array besides stuff that would be removed by `trim()`: the remnants of a prior, longer, message for example.